# ViewHolder in ListView adapter not working

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, universal-image-loader

I've been trying to make my ListView scroll smoother with ViewPager, but it keeps crashing. I've tried around 3 types of solution. The screen opens, the loading indicator shows but after a while (about 3-5 seconds) it crashes. To load images from URL do I use [Universal-Image-Loader lib](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) by nostra13. It all worked well without adding the ViewHolder.

My LogCat and getView + ViewHolder in Adapter class:

**LogCat**

```
    01-30 17:01:53.713: E/AndroidRuntime(12702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 17:01:53.713: E/AndroidRuntime(12702): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 17:01:53.713: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at com.example.animalist.AnimalAdapter$1.onLoadingComplete(AnimalAdapter.java:123)
01-30 17:01:53.713: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayBitmapTask.run(DisplayBitmapTask.java:74)
01-30 17:01:53.713: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-30 17:01:53.713: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-30 17:01:53.713: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
01-30 17:01:53.713: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
01-30 17:01:53.713: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 17:01:53.713: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-30 17:01:53.713: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-30 17:01:53.713: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-30 17:01:53.713: E/AndroidRuntime(12702):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 17:01:57.957: I/wpa_supplicant(15739): Reset vh_switch_counter due to receive LINKSPEED cmd
```

**in AnimalAdapter.java - getView + ViewHolder**

```
 static class ViewHolder{
        TextView animalView;
        TextView areaView;
        ImageView notfound;
        ImageView animalPic;
        ProgressBar indicator;
    }
    
    
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        
        
        
        if(convertView == null){
              LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
              convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.animal_row_item, null);
              holder = new ViewHolder();
              
             holder.animalView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.animal_text);
              holder.areaView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.area_text);
            holder.notfound = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notfoundimg);
              holder.animalPic = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.animal_pic);
              holder.indicator = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
               convertView.setTag(holder);
          }
          
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    
        }  
        
          final Animal animal = mAnimals.get(position);
          
          
          
          
          holder.notfound.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          holder.indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          holder.animalPic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          
            //Setup a listener we can use to switch from the loading indicator to the Image once it's ready
            ImageLoadingListener listener = new ImageLoadingListener(){


                ViewHolder holder = null;
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {
                    holder.indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.animalPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.notfound.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View view, FailReason arg2) {
                    holder.notfound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.animalPic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

            };

            
            
          imageLoader.displayImage(animal.getImgUrl(), holder.animalPic,options, listener);
          holder.animalView.setText(animal.getAnimal());
          holder.areaView.setText(animal.getArea());
          
          
          
          
          
          convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MoreActivity.class);
                    
                    intent.putExtra("about", animal.getAbout());
                    intent.putExtra("animal", animal.getAnimal());
                    intent.putExtra("imgUrl", animal.getImgUrl());
                    getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
          });
          
          return convertView;
      }
```

Do you have any idea, how to improve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your 82th line of AnimalAdapter.java?

Comment: remove  `View vi = convertView;` and use  `if(convertView == null){` and  `convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.animal_row_item, null);`

Comment: hi thanks a lot for your answer, its true. but i get different (but i think less serious) error. Ive updated my code

Comment: I know it's 100% related to your question, but IMHO you should stop using universalimageloader and switch to Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) much simpler, more stable and more powerful.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation ! i will try it for sure

Comment: So ive tried it, it works easily and with no crashes. BUT it supports cache different way, so it takes some time to show the image with every scroll. But i really like the fade-effect when the image is being showed. Second 'but' i, that i cant make my ProgressBar as a .placeholder - it supports only Drawables. But anyways thanks for your recommendation. glad to try something new

Answer (score 3):

the fact the in the stacktrace you have

```
01-30 16:45:09.003: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1264)
01-30 16:45:09.003: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
```

suggests that the convertView you are returning is `null`.

About your second issue, your ViewHolder instance inside `ImageLoadingListener` is always `null`. You should take care to initialise it accordingly

Comment: And do you have any idea, how to initialise it better? Now it finally loads my text objects and when it comes to load images, it crashes. So the issue is definietly there

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is not right, in your `getView()` method you test:

```
if (vi == null){
```

But there you should test whether:

```
if (convertView == null) {
```

Try changing it, should work this way.

**---- EDIT ----**

The way you initialize your `ViewHolder` seems ok to me, afterwards you assign each instance a `View` via `findViewById()`, which is ok - If you're getting a `NullPointerException` setting the visibility, that means that for some reason the `findViewById()` returned a null object - i.e., it didn't find an id with the name `R.id.progress` (probably there is no such element in your layout with that name).

**---- EDIT ----**

Here goes an example of my adapter's `getView()` method:

```
public static class vhItem {
  TextView maintext;
  TextView topictext; 
  ImageView mainimage;
  TextView users; 
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
  vhItem viewHolder;

  if (convertView == null) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

    viewHolder = new vhItem();
    viewHolder.maintext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chanlist_chan);
    viewHolder.topictext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chanlist_topic);
    viewHolder.mainimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chanlist_featured);
    viewHolder.users = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chanlist_usercount);

    // I've set a contextual menu for each row this way, but it's not required
    ((Activity) context).registerForContextMenu(convertView);
  }
  else
    viewHolder = (vhItem) convertView.getTag();

  viewHolder.maintext.setText((String) getItem(position));
  viewHolder.mainimage.setTag(getItem(position));
  viewHolder.mainimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(final View v) {
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
      ...
      dialog.show();
    }
  });

  return convertView; 
}
```

Comment: in the first line of `getView` OP set `converView` to `vi`, this is not a problem

Comment: hi thanks a lot for your answer, its true. but i get different (but i think less serious) error. Ive updated my code

Comment: `holder.indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` when i remove it, it shows an error in column below and so on

Comment: @Marson `indicator` is null check the initialization and the id. all yur initializations are wrong

Comment: @Marson I've updated my answer, see if it fits your scenario.

Comment: Ive been wondering about it all night and still didnt figure it out. When i remove viewholder initialization from image-loading-listener it suggests me to make holder final, but when i set it, the statement holder = new ViewHolder(); suggests me to remove it.

Comment: You cannot make it `final` because that would mean that it **HAS** to be initialized at least once `getView()` is called. But that's not what you want as when `convertView` is not `null`, you simply get its tag but you don't initialize it again. I'll update my post with one of my `ArrayAdapter`'s `getView()` implementation, maybe you may see something you're missing.